# Chamfered border different container color CSS

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

**What I want to achieve :**

[image]

What I did so far is to make the corners as if it had the same color with the container and then cover the unneeded area with the "fake" square rotated by 45 deg.

I don't like that much the result, especially the bottom right corner and I can't thing another way to do it. What is the best way to achieve it ? Is it possible to be done with gradients ?

First Step : http://jsfiddle.net/laxmana/wjaAs/

Final : http://jsfiddle.net/laxmana/j9NWC/

**CSS :**

```
.chamfered-box{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #149E4B;
}

.chamfered-box::before, .chamfered-box::after{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.chamfered-box::after{
    right: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    border-top: 10px solid #149E4B;
    border-right: 10px solid white;
    border-left: 10px solid #149E4B;
    border-bottom: 10px solid white;
}

.chamfered-box::before{
    left: -1px;
    top: -1px;
    border-top: 10px solid #149E4B;
    border-right: 10px solid white;
    border-left: 10px solid #149E4B;
    border-bottom: 10px solid white;
}

.ch-top, .ch-bottom{position: absolute;z-index: 5;}

.ch-top{
    top: -16px;
    left: -18px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.ch-bottom{
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 6px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.ch-content{
    padding: 20px;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
    <div class="chamfered-box">
      <div class="ch-top"></div>
      <div class="ch-bottom"></div>
      <div class="ch-content">The text</div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the pseudo element and rotate them on top(over) of the container with a little difference from your method.

Draw an inset shadow instead a border to your container.

Draw squares with a white background (as container) with borders.

Rotate the square and hide part of them overflowing from container.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Gidky)**

---

```
.chamfered-box{
  margin:1em auto;
  width: 440px;
  padding:5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #149E4B;

}

.chamfered-box::before, .chamfered-box::after{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid #149E4B;  
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}

.chamfered-box::after{
  right: -11px;
  bottom: -11px;

}

.chamfered-box::before{
  left: -11px;
  top: -11px;

}
```